# Grass has completely disappeared despite consistent watering and fertilization

Tags: lawn, lawn-repair

I live in Arizona. My lawn has slowly disappeared over the last year. I water it regularly and fertilize it according to instructions. The area gets consistent sunshine. The grass is probably Bermuda.

I've noticed that the soil appears to have little "balls" on the surface. Like a tiny creature made them. It's time for me to plant winter grass, but am wary to proceed until I identify what's going on.

[image: bare soil despite being watered]

[image: bare soil despite being watered]